# Why this insert command on SQLite do nothing?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to android database development. below code is my first code. 
After executing this code, I see in my database table nothing is inserted.
What's wrong with my code?

This is my dbHelper class:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "shit.db", null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "create table users (userID integer primary key autoincrement,name text,family text,age integer);";
        Log.d("Ehsan", sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And this is the onCreate method of my main activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("Ehsan", "Started");

        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
        Log.d("Ehsan", "DB Created");
        SQLiteDatabase mydb =db.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("name", "Ehsan");
        cv.put("family", "Shirzadi");
        cv.put("age", 29);
        Log.d("Ehsan", "Record inserting");
        long id = mydb.insert("users",null, cv);
        Log.d("Ehsan", "Record inserted");
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Lokesh yes. but it's empty after running the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a few things:

At first remove semicolon `;` this character makes only problems. And second you specified age column as integer so you should put integer and not String into ContentValues:

```
cv.put("age", 29);
```

Now it should, works.

**Note:** Also columns are case-sensitive so you should keep same upper and lower cases. For  problems like this (incorrect column name) is generally recommended to use static fields which keep your column names:

```
public static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
...
```

Comment: SQLite doesn't use case sensitive column neither enforces column type definition...

Comment: It's interesting what you are saying because in my case (in past) if i defined column as Type and wrote type it didn't work for me. And also ContentValues should keep correct data-type! Code is more readable by another user.

Comment: What's your mean of remove semicolon? All commands in java need to end with semicolon and without that in throws a syntax error.

Comment: In Java if you are calling statements through code (for example JDBC also in Android)semicolon is not allowed.

Comment: Is it produce kind of error or warning which is can see in log cat?

Comment: I think yes (usually table is not created). Add here your logcat and things will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You specified the age field as an Integer, but you're trying to put a String in there.

Try this:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("Name", "Ehsan");
cv.put("Family", "Shirzadi");
cv.put("Age", 29);
Log.d("Ehsan", "Record inserting");
long id = mydb.insert("users",null, cv);
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: SQLite doesn't care about it.

Comment: is SQLite case sensitive? I noticed that his column names are all in small letters and when he inserts it, he capitalizes the first letter. Maybe that could be another problem?

Comment: I've corrected that but nothing happens and still no record in my table.